# Java inter type declarations

Tags: java

I need to implement inter type declarations in a java compiler. Can anyone tell me how can I edit the java compiler to accommodate class member declared by other classes in a java program?

Comment: First, what is an "inter type declaration"?  Second, your chosen solution is to edit the Java compiler?

Comment: yes i need to add a feature to the compiler itself. Anyone who has experience with java compiler development is welcome to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the source code of Oracle's Java compiler and Java runtime environment in the [OpenJDK project](http://openjdk.java.net/); that's a good place to start if you want to experiment with the Java compiler.